# ForEach pull value from loop and use value in a .sheet view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am coming from python and web development so still fairly new to Swift and SwiftData and all I want to do is loop through DataModel and pass certain data to sheet view. Any info you can share to help me understand would be helpful. Even just point me in the right direction is better then nothing. This is what I am working with:

```
 @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
 @Query private var accounts: [LedgerAccounts]
 @State var sheetEditAccount: Bool = false
```

```
ForEach(accounts) { account in
                        
                        let accountNumberString = account.numberOfAccount
                        let accountNumberStringValue = String(accountNumberString.suffix(4))
                        
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("#" + accountNumberStringValue)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                    .fontWeight(.thin)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                            }
                            VStack {
                                Text("\(account.nameOfAccount)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            }
                            VStack {
                                Text(account.amountOfAccount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false, content: {
                            // Edit Account
                            Button(action: {
                                sheetEditAccount.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "gearshape.arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                            })
                            .tint(Color.blue)
                            
                            Divider()
                            
                            // View Account
                            Button {

                                    } label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "eye.circle")
                                    }
                                    .tint(Color.gray)
                        })
                        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetEditAccount) {
                            print("Sheet Dismissed")
                        } content: {
                            EditAccountView()
                                .presentationDetents([.medium])
                                
                        }
```

I have searched google and stackoverflow not sure if I am asking the right question. Cause I have yet to find something that makes since to me.

Comment: You have 12 open curly brackets as opposed to 11 closed ones.

Comment: `.sheet(item:)`

Comment: That’s just snippets not all the code but I just want to store data say nameOfAccount value in variable and pass it to .sheet view don’t want to pull all of the values for nameOfAccount just the one on that part of the loop

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `.sheet(item: ...)` (as mentioned by @lorem ipsum), such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //....
    
    @State var selectedAccount: LedgerAccounts? //<--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(accounts) { account in
            //....
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false, content: {
                // Edit Account
                Button(action: {
                    selectedAccount = account //<--- here
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                })
                //....
           } // end of ForEach
            
            .sheet(item: $selectedAccount) { account in //<--- here
                EditAccountView(account: account)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
            // ...
```

Comment: The `sheet` shouldn't be inside the `ForEach` it would attempt to present `accounts.count` number of sheets

Comment: you are just too quick. I was editing the answer as you commented.

Comment: How can I take the sheet out of the view when I have the button in the swipe actions? Also I will give @workingdogsupportUkraine answer a try to see if it’ll work if I can’t find anything else then count

Comment: you cannot `take` the sheet out of the `View`, this is how SwiftUI works. I suggest you read more about SwiftUI.

Comment: I didn’t mean view I meant the ForEach.

Comment: it must be outside the `ForEach` loop. The `selectedAccount = account` will trigger the sheet to pop up with the correct account.

Comment: I will give this a try and I appreciate the effort. I know how to in other languages but for some reason can’t quite break it down in my head in swift and SwiftUI. Will give it a go and keep reading the documentation on swiftdata.

Comment: The way `.sheet(item: ...)` works is, nothing will happen while `selectedAccount` is nil.
Then as soon as you set `selectedAccount = account` the sheet will pop up with the selected account.
When you are finished with the sheet, `selectedAccount` will be reset to `nil` again, just by itself, SwiftUI magic. You are then ready to tap on another `account` button.